# React - How to return to previous pagination page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

My react application has the react-router v4 with the following search filter function:

```
  filterList = (e) => {
    let { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ value }, () => {
        var searchValue = this.state.value.toLowerCase();
        var updatedList = this.state.holder;
        updatedList = updatedList.filter((item) => {
            return Object.keys(item).some(key => item[key].toString().toLowerCase().search(searchValue) !== -1);
        });
            this.setState({ books: updatedList });
    });
  }
```

When I edit, it will route to edit page.
When edit finish it route back, how can I route back with remain search result?

Comment: You may need to use a state management for that. Maybe `redux` will work for you.

Comment: How does it route back? Can pass state objects through router commands and in `<Redirect>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Link component from react-router and specify `to={}` as an object where you specify pathname as the route to go to. Then add a variable e.g. `searchResult` to hold the value you want to pass on. See the example below.

Using the `<Link />` component:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/page",
    searchResult: this.state.searchResult
  }}
>
```

Using `history.push()`

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/page',
  searchResult: this.state.searchResult
})
```

Using either of the above options you now can access `searchResult` on the location object as per the below in your page component.

```
render() {
  const { searchResult } = this.props.location
  return (
    // render logic here
  )
}
```

You can see an example of how to pass a value along with a route in another example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rywo1xx6xn).

Comment: I am trying to doing the same thing, navigate between list and detail pages. And I am trying to pass searchResult:<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/detail",
    searchResult: this.state.searchResult
  }}
> from list to detail. in Detail component,  <Link
        to={{
          pathname: "/",
          searchResult:  this.props.location.state
        }}
      >
        <button>Return to list</button>
      </Link>  But it doesn't work for me. Can you explain more?